# Mysql update or insert if composite primary key matches

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the columns (`store_id`, `emp_id`, `shift_id`, `name`) where `store_id`, `emp_id` and `shift_id` is a composite key.

I want to check first if the key is already present in table, then update name, otherwise insert new record.

Comment: pls show code you have tried

Comment: The linked question is slightly different but accepted answer mentions exactly what you want (`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`).